# eval() not working while object iteration

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to execute the following code snippet..

```
var sUserID = "HELLO".toUpperCase();
                var oAlphabets = {
                    "A": 1,
                    "B": 2,
                    "C": 3,
                    "D": 4,
                    "E": 5,
                    "F": 6,
                    "G": 7,
                    "H": 8,
                    "I": 9,
                    "J": 10,
                    "K": 11,
                    "L": 12,
                    "M": 13,
                    "N": 14,
                    "O": 15,
                    "P": 16,
                    "Q": 17,
                    "R": 18,
                    "S": 19,
                    "T": 20,
                    "U": 21,
                    "V": 22,
                    "W": 23,
                    "X": 24,
                    "Y": 25,
                    "Z": 26
                };
                var iEncoded = 0, sEncoded;
                for (var i in sUserID) {
                    var sEval = "oAlphabets."+sUserID[i];
                    iEncoded = iEncoded + eval(sEval);
                }
                if(iEncoded <100){
                    sEncoded = "0"+iEncoded;
                }
                else{
                    sEncoded = ""+iEncoded;
                }
```

It works as expected in Chrome and returned the result 078. However, it gave the error "Expected ;" in IE 11.

What is the issue here and how to get rid of it..

Regards,

Fahad Hamsa

Comment: There is zero reason to use eval. bracket notation is all you need....

Comment: As said by @epascarello there's no reason to use `eval`, you can just use `var sEval = oAlphabets[sUserID[i]];` and then `iEncoded = iEncoded + sEval`

Comment: Minor note `iEncoded` - that's Hungarian notation that says `Encoded` is of type integer. But when you do `iEncoded = iEncoded + eval(sEval);` it's being turned into a string.

Comment: That code **does not** produce the claimed error in IE11, and it is not expected too. (Maybe a stale JavaScript file cached?)

Comment: Agreed. I am getting back `"052"` when trying in IE11. Is there other code present, like something modifying `String.prototype`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is Zero reason to use eval. Just use bracket notation like it is meant to be used with variables.

```
iEncoded += oAlphabets[sUserID[i]];
```

Comment: To add to that since it's technically correct open any developer console in any browser. After the object is declared type `oAlphabets['a']`. If you set `oAlphabets.a = 123;` then `console.log(oAlphabets['a'])` will also return 123. JavaScript is highly dynamic and there are lots of ways to do the same thing to the extent that they almost effectively killed error handling.

Comment: I did not think about this approach.. 
By the way, what was the issue with eval()!!.. Strange thing is: It gave error in my office laptop, but not in my personal laptop. Both have IE 11..